# How do I deploy just a single function to my slot in my Azure Function App, instead of all the functions?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I have 2 Azure functions in a Function app and I was wondering if I can deploy just 1 of the 2 functions, instead of both?

Here is the way I deploy and maybe it can be done a different way or maybe I need to move my 2 functions into separate function apps?

1. From the cli I publish the function app, but I think the functions are built and published when I select deploy in the next step. So this step might be unnecessary.

> >dotnet publish --configuration Debug /p:EnvironmentName=Development

2. Under my subscription in the Azure tab I select the function app then the slot I want to use, then right click on the slot and select "deploy to slot"
   [image]

**PROBLEM** - This builds and deploys both functions.

**QUESTION** - Is there a way to deploy just 1 of the 2 different functions or should I create another function app?

**FYI** - 1 function consumes messages from a service bus queue and the other function is a Http trigger that receives webhooks from an online service.

Comment: You will need to use another function app if you want to deploy them seperately

Comment: @Peter Bons ok, it that recommended? I tried adding another project and now I'm getting a message window that 's asking me to set the default function. It seems as though VS Code has issues with running and attaching the debugger with multiple function app projects in my solution. I also read from another SO post that you just deploy all functions, and assume you haven't made any changes to the other functions, which I guess works fine, until you inadvertently make a change to another function that ends up breaking it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy individual Function triggers in the Deployment slot, As Deployment Slot is a set at the Function App level and not Functions level. You can have multiple functions in your Function app with Service bus trigger and HTTP trigger but Deployment slot will be applicable on Function app level,

> Refer this document:-
>
> [Azure Functions deployment slots | Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots)

***I agree to **@Peter bons** You can deploy one Function app with Service Bus Queue trigger Function and add that Function app to one Deployment Slot and Create another Function app with HTTP Trigger Function and that Function app in another Deployment slot keeping the Configuration Settings same in both the Function App in order for them to work***

***I created one Service Bus queue Trigger in one Function app and added the Function app to one Deployment Slot. Refer below:-***

You need to keep one Deployment slot as Production, One Deployment slot is created by Default with Function app set to Production, You can swap another deployment slot and make it Live as Production for the Function App to run on it.

[image]

[image]

***Created one HTTP Trigger in another Function app and added it to another Deployment Slot.***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Make sure you keep the configuration settings same in both the Function App :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. The slots aren't what I'm questioning. Should have 2 functions in 1 Function App or 2 separate function apps for my 2 functions? 1 function gets web hooks and the other function receives service bus messages, so both are completely different and independent of each other, but BOTH are used for the same website. I'm just trying to create the correct infrastructure before I go live. From a doc I read it seems like it's probably ok to keep both functions in 1 app, as long as I don't modify the 2nd function, when working on the first

Comment: @user1186050 Yes, You can keep both the functions in same function app instead of keeping them in the separate function apps. As that would reduce your Cost and maintaining other app. And You can have multiple functions independent of each other running inside a single function app.